# Matching email addresses to first name using regex in Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

We've been hit by a lot of accounts creations and I'm trying to filter out anything that does not match between email-address column that contains a name and match that towards a column with first names.

I would like to find a way to compare these using regex, and yes, I expect a lot of ones to mismatch when no name is given in the email-address.

Example:

```
email_address      | first_name | bool
john.doe@gmail.com | john       | true
john.doe@gmail.com | Sonny      | false
```

Comment: Hi there, is there anything you've tried already that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `like`:

```
select
    email_address,
    first_name,
    email_address like first_name || '%' bool
from mytable
```

This checks if the email address *starts* with the first name.

If you want a case-insensitive match, you can use `ilike` instead of `like`.

For a more precise match on the first name, and assuming that emails are always in the for `<first_name>.<last_name>@....`, you could do:

```
email_address like first_name || '.%'
```

Comment: Worked FLAWLESSLY, truly appreciated!